# Change particular ListTile Icon in ListView.builder

Tags: android, flutter, dart, mobile

I am relatively new to Flutter and Dart so I have a question regarding ListView manipulation. Currently, code bellow works and displays some basic information inside ListView.
How would I implement a solution so that when I click on particular List Tile, its Icon changes to something else? Below is my current stock code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    ));


class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {

  Widget _getListItemTile(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Card(
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: ListTile(
          leading: Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank),
          title: Text('My Item'),
          onTap: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Test App'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: 7,
        itemBuilder: _getListItemTile,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Tell us whether your code works and you want to improve it, or does it fail? If so, why, what's wrong with it? Please see "[ask]", "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)" and "[MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)" and all their linked pages help explain what we need to know. Currently you haven't told us enough so we'll have to guess, which isn't the SO way.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can copy paste run full code below 
You can declare a `List<bool>` and change `leading` icon by `boolList[index]` 
code snippet

```
List<bool> boolList = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true];
...
Card(
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: ListTile(
          leading: boolList[index]
              ? Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank)
              : Icon(Icons.place),
          title: Text('My Item'),
          onTap: () {
            boolList[index] = !boolList[index];
            setState(() {});
          },
        ),
      ),
    )
```

working demo

[image]

full code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MaterialApp(
      home: HomePage(),
    ));

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  List<bool> boolList = [true, true, true, true, true, true, true];

  Widget _getListItemTile(BuildContext context, int index) {
    return Card(
      child: GestureDetector(
        child: ListTile(
          leading: boolList[index]
              ? Icon(Icons.check_box_outline_blank)
              : Icon(Icons.place),
          title: Text('My Item'),
          onTap: () {
            boolList[index] = !boolList[index];
            setState(() {});
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('My Test App'),
        centerTitle: true,
      ),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: boolList.length,
        itemBuilder: _getListItemTile,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```